# Other ways to use Maven with liquibase plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, liquibase

I have been using the command prompt to generate changelog files using the liquibase plugin with Maven. I was wondering if there are any good GUI or any other ways to use Maven so that I don't have to remember all the commands such as "generateChangeLog" and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`$ mvn liquibase:help` ?

This command dumps the command names of the liquibase plugin.

In case you use NetBeans, look here: http://www.liquiface.org/

For Eclipse users: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liquibase-eclipse-plugin